# Best way to create dynamo db tables using shell script

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to create dynamo db tables using shell script.

I am able to create using java, but i want to create it without java.

Is there any way to create dynamo db tables by running script which will not use

java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create tables with the AWS CLI tool.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html

Example:

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name category \ 
                      --attribute-definitions AttributeName=category_id,AttributeType=S \
                      --key-schema AttributeName=category_id,KeyType=HASH \
                      --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code examples in AWS GITHUB, you will notice there are many different languages that have an example that shows you how to create a DynamoDB table. For example, here is the example for JavaScript.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/dynamodb/ddb_createtable.js

Likewise, here is the PHP example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/php/example_code/dynamodb/SampleDataCreateTables.php

There are other examples too in different languages.